# How to use SuggestionSpan?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I'm trying to add some custom suggestions to my EditText:

```
SuggestionSpan suggestionSpan = new SuggestionSpan(this, new String[]{"qweasd","mySuggestion", "suggestion2", "anything"}, FLAG_AUTO_CORRECTION);

EditText editView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_view);
Editable text = editView.getText();

text.setSpan(suggestionSpan,0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
editView.setText(text);
```

This doesn't seem to work, I can't see any of those in the suggestions when typing/focusing the text.

Is there something missing in this implementation?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain, unfortunately I can't, the EditText is not controlled by my code (EditText is on app layer and I'm working on a library layer part)

Comment: when you are typing then you need to add `textwatcher` for continuously getting the updated text. hope it helps

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain, I'll try the textWatcher, thanks